# How to save measured time in Rails 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a js timer and I need to save the time in format: hour minute second.
Like you know `Timer.new(hour, minute, sec)` (similar).
How can i save an interval time in rails db? I just need to know how to save it, i know ho to handle ajax/controller stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options. You can create two timestamp columns within your database like this:

```
create_table "your_table", force: true do |t|
  # ...
  t.timestamp "started_at"
  t.timestamp "ended_at"
end
```

Or you can create one timestamp and one integer column:

```
create_table "your_table", force: true do |t|
  # ...
  t.timestamp "started_at"
  t.integer  "elapsed_time"
 end
```

Or you store only elapsed time:

```
create_table "your_table", force: true do |t|
  # ...
  t.integer  "elapsed_time"
end
```

`started_at` and `ended_at` should be a `timestamp` or `datetime`, in my point of view. I would not only store `time`, because it makes calculations much more easier. For instance when `started_at` is today and `ended_at` tomorrow.

Keep in mind that it is database dependent if Rails stores time values with a precision in seconds or microseconds.